# Linqpad 6 (Core) and .Net Core Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, linqpad

Linqpad 6 supports .Net Core.
When I create a new empty .Net Core API solution in visual studio , I get a simple template with a simple demo controller.

[image]

When I run it in visual studio it uses a command-line server (kestrel) to run the project :

[image]

So I wanted to see if I can run this project in Linqpad 6.

So I've installed all nugets and copied the code to Linqpad :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwRyU.png

```
void Main()
{

    CreateWebHostBuilder(new string[] { "" }).Build().Run();

}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

}


public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

I do see that it is now listening :

[image]

But calls to `http://localhost:5000/api/values` do get acked , but without the json value response from controller :

[image]

**Question:**

How can I get Linqpad to return the value from the controller? ( a simple json)

Comment: Could you please post at least the code as text, and not as an image? Makes it easier for others to test as well.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen it's in the link in the question  : https://jsbin.com/zovicuduto/edit?html . I've pasted it as an image so people will see how it's displayed in Linqpad. If I paste it , the code of the controller will be too long.

Comment: How are you making the request?

Comment: @ChrisPratt via Browser. https://i.imgur.com/3w2GBCX.jpg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a difference in the way LINQPad executes code that could account for this not working.

Being a scripting tool, LINQPad wraps everything in a class (otherwise, the `Main` method would have nowhere to live). So `ValuesController` is actually ends up as a nested type, `UserQuery.ValuesController`, and this could potentially upset the routing API.

For such situations, LINQPad has the ability to extract all nested types and move them outside UserQuery (using the Roslyn API). To enable this, add the following to the start of your query:

```
#LINQPad nonest
```

Something else to consider is that a default MVC project includes an appsettings.json file. Should this be required for your code in LINQPad, you need to create such a file and add a reference to it (when you reference to a non-binary file, LINQPad copies it into the output folder, which is exactly where appsettings.json needs to be).

Edit: [There's now a checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX1E4.jpg) in the **Query Properties** dialog to add ASP.NET Core references to a query in LINQPad 6. This pulls the assemblies straight from the shared framework folder, and is easier than finding the right NuGet packages.

Comment: It works ! ( appsettings must be added  like you said) - https://i.imgur.com/9v8xpo1.jpg.

Thanks a lot Joe.